# My PostgreSQL code for foreign key gives foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

my code :

```
create table courses(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
)
----------------------
create table teachers(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
)
----------------------

CREATE TABLE assignments(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    given_date TIMESTAMP,
    deadline TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES courses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id) REFERENCES teachers(id),
    pass_mark INT,
    full_mark INT,
    description TEXT,
    assignment_file VARCHAR(100)

);
```

error:

```
column "course_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

i tried running the third create table code after inserting data in the courses and teachers table's id yet no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reference a column like that. First you have add the column you want to create foreign key then reference it.

```
create table courses(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
);
----------------------
create table teachers(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY 
);
----------------------

CREATE TABLE assignments(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    given_date TIMESTAMP,
    deadline TIMESTAMP,
    course_id INT,
    teacher_id INT,
    pass_mark INT,
    full_mark INT,
    description TEXT,
    assignment_file VARCHAR(100),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES courses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(teacher_id) REFERENCES teachers(id)

);
```